# How to center view on border of another view?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have looked around and haven't found an answer. I am building one of my apps for Android and I can't find a way to achieve this: [iOS App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP46E.jpg)

I did it easily for iOS but I'm having trouble with Android. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is what I have at the moment on my Android app: [Android App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztjTi.png)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/chronoBgColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shockTimerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-heavy"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textColor="@color/chronoFontColor"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/shockTimerButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/shockColor"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="SHOCK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activityCountTextView"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use negative margin

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and turns out i needed to have clipChildren to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shockTimerTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-heavy"
            tools:text="00:00:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shockTimerButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            tools:text="SHOCK"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityCountTextView"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="0" />
    
</FrameLayout>
```

this produces:

[image]

Comment: This was great! Thanks! I also used android:clipChildren="false" because I am nesting LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

To achive this look you can add the following line of code to your shockTimerButton view:

```
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
```

8dp was used as this is half the width of your activityCountTextView view.

So the final solution would look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@color/chronoBgColor"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shockTimerTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-heavy"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/chronoFontColor"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shockTimerButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/shockColor"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="SHOCK"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityCountTextView"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```